# Get an NSWindow object from NSWorkspace?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have the following which opens TextEdit using a Cocoa objective-c application:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/Users/abs/Documents/my.txt" withApplication:@"TextEdit"]; 

 NSDictionary * currentAppInfo = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activeApplication];

 int pid = [[currentAppInfo objectForKey: @"NSApplicationProcessIdentifier"] intValue];
```

However, I am trying to get a `NSWindow` object or the likes for the application that I've just opened. So I can set height and width and various other things. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppleScript is the way to go:

```
set theFile to "/Users/Anne/Desktop/File.txt"
tell application "TextEdit"
    open (POSIX file theFile) as alias
    set bounds of window 1 to {10, 10, 100, 100}
end tell
```

Use `NSAppleScript` to run the script:

```
NSString *path = @"/Users/Anne/Desktop/File.txt";

int X = 10;
int Y = 10;
int width = 400;
int height = 800;

NSString *theSource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""
                       "set theFile to \"%@\"\n"
                       "tell application \"TextEdit\"\n"
                       "open (POSIX file theFile) as alias\n"
                       "set bounds of window 1 to {%d, %d, %d, %d}\n"
                       "end tell",
                       path,X,Y,width,height];

NSAppleScript *theScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:theSource];
[theScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can’t imagine how that’s possible (what if you opened a Carbon app? or the app didn’t open a window at all?).

Sometimes the Accessibility API lets you do things of this nature.

Comment: I will always be opening TextEdit or the likes that has a window. I will also have to check if the window has been opened.